# Как можно сравнить со всеми дочерними элементами сразу?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Писал dropdown связанный с табами на jQuery.

Все правильно работает, но понимаю, что код далеко не идеален, в особенности данная конструкция:

```
if(e.target != $('.select--double-level')[0] && e.target != $('.select__name')[0] && e.target != $('.select__arrrow-bottom')[0] && e.target != $('.select__arrrow-top')[0] && e.target != $('.select__category')[0] && e.target != $('.select__arrrow-top').find('use')[0]) {
            $('.select__menu').fadeOut();
        }
```

Тут по сути исключается нажатие на все дочерние элементы. Как можно сделать это более изящно?

```js
//Select

$('.select--double-level').click(function() {
  $(this).find('.select__menu').fadeIn();
})

$('.select').click(function() {
  $('.select').each(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('select--active')) {
      $(this).removeClass('select--active');
    }

  })

  $(this).addClass('select--active');
})

$('.select__line').click(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  $(this.parentNode.parentNode).find('.select__category').text(text);
  $(this.parentNode.parentNode).addClass('select--active')
})


$('.select__arrrow-bottom').click(function(e) {
  $(this.parentNode).fadeOut();
  e.stopPropagation();
})

$(document).click(function(e) {
  console.log(e.target)
  if (e.target != $('.select--double-level')[0] && e.target != $('.select__name')[0] && e.target != $('.select__arrrow-bottom')[0] && e.target != $('.select__arrrow-top')[0] && e.target != $('.select__category')[0] && e.target != $('.select__arrrow-top').find('use')[0]) {
    $('.select__menu').fadeOut();
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="select-block">
  <div class="select select--double-level">
    <div class="select__name">
      <div class="select__category">
        Регистрация компаний
      </div>
      <svg class='select__arrrow select__arrrow-top'>
        <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#arrow-drop"/>
       </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="select__menu">
      <svg class='select__arrrow-bottom'>
        <use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#arrow-drop"/>
       </svg>
      <div class="select__line select__tab--js" data-link='comp-reg'>
        Регистрация компаний
      </div>
      <div class="select__line select__tab--js" data-link='euro-comp'>
        Европейские компании
      </div>
      <div class="select__line select__tab--js" data-link='offshore'>
        Оффшоры
      </div>
      <div class="select__line select__tab--js" data-link='asia'>
        Азия
      </div>
      <div class="select__line select__tab--js" data-link='america'>
        Америка
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="select-block">
  <div class="select">
    <div class="select__name select__tab--js" data-link='bank-acc'>
      Банковские счета
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="select-block">
  <div class="select">
    <div class="select__name select__tab--js" data-link='accounting'>
      Бухгалтерия
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="select-block">
  <div class="select">
    <div class="select__name select__tab--js" data-link='tax-plan'>
      Налоговое планирование
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(e.target).is('.select__menu')` не подходит ?

Comment: ох ёжики, как вообще можно было такое написать-то? Вы напишите конкретный пример, что вы хотите исключить и что с чем связать. Ибо пишите про дропдауны и табы, а в коде какие то лютые обработчики кликов вообще на все что имеется.

Comment: код вида `.select  -> each -> hasClass -> removeClass`, можно заменить просто на `$(".select.my-class").removeClass('my-class')`